# Additive structure of polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, additive-combinatorics

I've been wondering recently about results for irreducibility that use the "additive structure" of the polynomial ring at hand. For instance, can we say anything about the irreducibility of a sum of two irreducible polynomials that satisfy some conditions? This seems like an additive number theory problem but in a different context. I searched the literature for stuff along these lines but did not find much. Am I missing something obvious (like maybe I can be asking the same questions in the underlying ring) or is this just a question with sparse literature around it? Any papers involving similar questions would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: The number theoretic parallel to your explicit question is "given two primes, are there conditions that tell us information about the primality of the sum of the two primes?". I think the answer is that there are no interesting (read: not immediate) conditions known, whether asked for polynomials or integers. Would love to be shown that I'm wrong!

Comment: At first glance, the abc conjecture seems relevant. My guess is that this is a very hard question so there may not be much to say.

Comment: @RghtHndSd Yeah, I guess there's not so much hope for nontrivial conditions that would guarantee irreducibility, but here's an example: $(x^{2}+2x+1)p(x)+x$ seems to be irreducible for "almost all" p(x) with nonzero constant term. Unsure how I'd show this. [Here's a paper](https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/colloquium-mathematicum/all/99/1/87028/on-the-irreducibility-of-0-1-polynomials-of-the-form-f-x-x-n-g-x) (that I have not fully read) that has the flavor of problems that I'm interested in.

Comment: Now posted also on MO: [Results on additive structure of polynomial rings?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/346614) When [meta-tag:cross-posting], it is [recommended to link the posts to each other](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088).